# OleDb reading database and filling in textboxes using combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox, textbox, oledb

Okay, i have adjusted the code to what i was recommended here, but only TxtNaamprev.Text and TxtAdresprev.Text will fill...
can someone fill out the missing link? i really have no idea what i'm doing. this is a school task beyond what our book explains; i have no reference but the internet.

```
Private Sub CbbNaamfirma_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As                                               System.EventArgs) Handles CbbNaamfirma.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim cnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
                Application.StartupPath & "\Database.accdb"
    Dim query = "SELECT Adres FROM TblKlanten WHERE [Naam firma] = ?"
    Using Connection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(cnString)
        Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, Connection)
            Try
                Connection.Open()
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", CbbNaamfirma.Text)
                Using Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    While Reader.Read
                        TxtNaamprev.Text = CbbNaamfirma.Text
                        Dim posAdres = Reader.GetOrdinal("Adres")
                        TxtAdresprev.Text = Reader.GetString(posAdres)

                        Dim posTelefoonnummer = Reader.GetOrdinal("Telefoonnummer")
                        TxtTelefoonprev.Text = Reader.GetInt16(posTelefoonnummer)

                        Dim posFaxnummer = Reader.GetOrdinal("Faxnummer")
                        TxtFaxprev.Text = Reader.GetString(posFaxnummer)

                        Dim posGSM = Reader.GetOrdinal("GSM")
                        TxtGsmprev.Text = Reader.GetString(posGSM)

                        Dim posBTW = Reader.GetOrdinal("BTW-nummer")
                        TxtBTWprev.Text = Reader.GetString(posBTW)

                        Dim posWebsite = Reader.GetOrdinal("Website")
                        TxtWebsiteprev.Text = Reader.GetString(posWebsite)

                        Dim posNaambank = Reader.GetOrdinal("Naam bank")
                        TxtBankprev.Text = Reader.GetString(posNaambank)

                        Dim posIBAN = Reader.GetOrdinal("IBAN-nummer")
                        TxtIBANprev.Text = Reader.GetString(posIBAN)

                        Dim posBIC = Reader.GetOrdinal("BIC-code")
                        TxtBICprev.Text = Reader.GetString(posBIC)
                    End While
                End Using
            Catch ex As OleDbException
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: try this: `TxtGsmprev.Text = Reader.Item(THE COLUMN NAME).ToString` to fetch the data, but your query is only set to SELECT one column.

Answer (score 0):

As Plutonix pointed out, your SELECT query is only selecting one column (`Adres`).  The other columns you want are being returned because the query doesn't ask for them.  You can either use `*` to get all columns for the record(s) that match the WHERE criteria, or you can list each column you want, separating each column name by a `,`, like this:

```
Dim query = "SELECT Adres, Telefoonnummer, Faxnummer, GSM, BTW-nummer, Website, [Naam bank], IBAN-nummer, BIC-code FROM TblKlanten WHERE [Naam firma] = ?"
```

Or

```
Dim query = "SELECT * FROM TblKlanten WHERE [Naam firma] = ?"
```

Also, as Plutonix suggested, you can use the column name to get the value of the column.  Since you're assigning the values to TextBoxes, you'll want the string:

```
TxtAdresprev.Text = Reader("Adres").ToString()
TxtTelefoonprev.Text = Reader("Telefoonnumer").ToString()
' And so on.....
```

There's no need to convert from `Object` to the underlying data type when the ultimate destination is expecting a `String`.